# Laptop Speakers rattle?

Tags: laptop, speakers, noise

I have a Dell XPS 15 l501x, 
its known for its excellent JBL speakers and the sound is truly tremendous and impressive. However when I crank up the volume more than halfway the right speaker starts making a rattle like grains of sand resonating in high pitched frequencies on glass. When i put the palm of my hand on the right side of the keyboard, where the sound seems to be being produced the high pitched rattle goes away, or at least highly minimized. What is this, and is this a hardware issue related to the speaker? Or something more simplistic? I have recently vacuumed the keyboard as well to make sure its no physical particle making the noise.
Thank you!

Btw. the laptop is still in warranty so I could have it looked it if I need to.

[image]

Comment: Well, the only way to know for sure is to take a look at the speakers.  To do that you will have to disassemble the laptop though, which if you are willing to do may reveal more clues.

Comment: I figured it out, it was some of the keyboard keys which is lame because there is no real solution other than to put something on the keys when you want to crank it up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had this after disassembling to replace the hdd.
In my case it turned out to be the flat cable that comes from the power button and goes around, passing near the right speaker. It's somewhat loose (that's normal) and it was vibrating to the speaker.
I basically opened it up again, poked that cable, closed back again and the rattling was gone.

You can do it by following [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Jsr1FKpX7jE&t=72) up to detaching the palmrest (1:12)

Comment: This is an old question, however years later I did open the laptop and I used insulation tape around the plastic near the speaker to stop any vibrations causing rattling.

Comment: Getting a similar issue with my Zephyrus G14. What do laptop speakers typically look like? I couldn't identify it in the disassembly video for that model

Comment: @pete in the Dell XPS the speakers are those chrome concave circles on the left and right edges of the laptop